# Laplace equation unit sphere

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Laplec Equation is given by $\Delta u=0$ with $\Delta u=\sum_{i=1}^{n}u_{x_ix_i}$

Now I am confused with the following: What are solutions of Laplace Eq. for the inner of the unit sphere, which has on the surface the same values as $f_1(x_1,x_2,x_3)=x_1x_2, f_2(x_1,x_2,x_3)=x_1^2, f_3(x_1,x_2,x_3)=x_1^2+x_2^2, f_4(x_1,x_2,x_3)=x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2$

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You should have *at least* checked that the given functions aren't harmonic themselves... $f_1$ is. Also, there's something very simple about the behaviour of  $f_4$ on the sphere.

Comment: $f_1$ is the only function that satifies Laplace => Harmonic, right? $f_4$ describes a sphere, dou you mean that? The problem for me, I do not know how to calculate the solutions.

Answer (score 1):

All of the given functions have *constant* Laplacian. For $f_1$ it's already zero. Others will need to be modified inside without changing their values on the boundary. Thus, the solutions will be $F_k=f_k+g_k$ where $\Delta g_k$ is an appropriate constant, and $g_k=0$ on the boundary. Hint below.

> Hint: $g_k$ will be a constant multiple of $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2-1$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but could you explain me a little more in detail how to receive $F_k$ ?

Comment: @voyage If function $f$ has $\Delta f = 5$ and another function $g$ has $\Delta g=2$, can you find a constant $c$ such that $f+cg$ is harmonic?